# To pass JSF expression language as parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

i want to excecute javascript function on click of command button by passing JSF expression language function as parameter to javascript function.My command button is as below

```
<h:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="GO" action="#{workSpaceBean.submit}" onclick="checkOption(#{workSpaceBean.submit()})" />
```

I am getting error as failed to parse expression.Could you please tell me the correct way to do it.If it is not possible is it possible to pass and store value returned from the method of the managed bean in JSF page and use this as parameter to the js function.

Comment: I dont really get what you are trying to do, please explain it a little bit clearer. Passing the value returned from a method expression to a js-function is possible.

Comment: I need to first evaluate the javascript function and based on parameter passed to the javascript function the function returns true or false.If the function returns false the action event should not get executed or else it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a variable from backing bean to a javascript method,

Create a variable in beacking bean, say `myVariable` (add getter method)

Add `a4j:support` to your button as follows,

```
<h:commandButton action="#{workSpaceBean.submit}"......>
    <a4j:support event="click" onComplete="checkOption('#{workSpaceBean.myVariable}')" />
</h;commandButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to your own question I think that you looking for the use of `return false;` in your `onclick` that `return false;` will prevent from your `action` to be called

```
<h:commandButton id="cmdBtn" value="GO" action="#{workSpaceBean.submit}" onclick="return checkOption();" />
```

while in your `checkOption` you must return `false` when the check is failed (or whatever your condition is)

Comment: But i need to pass value returned by submit function to javascript function and based on the parameter value i need to return 'return false' or 'return true'